# Extraction probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have an urn with 40 balls of those 12 are white 11 are red and 17 are green. We extract 6 of them. We must find the probability that 3 are white 2 are red and 1 is green.

The solution should be 0,054

I'm struggling with these arguments and I didn't find some clear explanations about them,as far as I've understood we shouldn't use combinatorics when we don't have equiprobable spaces, which should be the case of this example since every color has a different probability to be extracted. Searching on the web (in italian) I've seen similar examples that use combinatorics, I've tried to apply those solutions for my problem but none of them gave me the expected result, what am I missing?

Comment: Hint:  imagine the balls are all numbered.  Then there are $\binom {40}6$ unrestricted ways to choose six.  How many ways satisfy the restriction?

Comment: if we want six of them based on the number only six satisfy the restriction right? for example that happens if we wanted the balls from 1 to 6

Comment: If the balls are distinguishable/numbered then ther are $\binom{12}3\binom{11}2\binom{17}1$  ways to choose $6$ balls under the restrictions mentioned in your question. A selection of $3$ white balls out of  a total of $12$ white balls, $2$ red balls out of a total of $11$ red balls and $1$ green ball out of $17$ green balls.

Comment: so the solution is : positive cases (drhab) / unrestricted ways (lulu)

Comment: Yes, that is the probability asked for.